# Can we run MPI programs in single system or is it imperative to run it in a cluster only?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

I have access to a clustered network at my college using PelicanHPC where In run various MPI programs, but at home I want to practice writing/using other MPI programs. Is there a way that I can run MPI programs on my own system?

(I work on Ubuntu Jaunty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So according to http://idea.uab.es/mcreel/ParallelKnoppix/, on PelicanHPC "The LAM-MPI and OpenMPI implementations of MPI are installed."

I don't know about LAM-MPI, but I know OpenMPI will automatically balance threads across multiple processors, as long as you don't ask for more threads than processors. This means that with a dual-core computer, you can "mpirun -n 2" to your heart's content. However, if you want to "mpirun -n 8" with true parallelism, you'd need 4 dual-core boxes.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the MPI runtime you use (you will need the runtime - something like [mpich](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/)). I guess in any case you can run the program in several processes, but if you run more processes then you have processor cores you will have less parallelism.

Comment: well  i have intel core 2 duo 32 bit machine .  can i run in different cores and also check the performace ? if yes is there any tool which can help me achive  that ?

under the pretext of runtime , is mpich only runtime available for mpi programs .. or there are others too ?

Comment: I'm not really sure - you'll have to read the MPI runtime documentation - but it's higly likely you can run the program as two processes on two cores. mpich is definitely not the only MPI runtime, there're others, including LAM/MPI, Intel MPI and whatever you can find with "MPI runtime" Google search.